# Setting enviromental variables for login shells under root account in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, root, environment-variables, gridengine, bourne-shell

I am currently in the process of configuring [Open Grid Scheduler](http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/) in FreeBSD. As part of this process I need to set the environmental variable`SGE_ROOT`as root.

To do this I have been experimenting with attempting to set this value through the root account's `~/.profile` since this account has been configured to use the Bourne shell as it's default shell. I have exported `SGE_ROOT` as follows: `export SGE_ROOT="/usr/local/sge"`

However upon logging into the root shell with `SGE_ROOT` configured in it's `~/.profile` it would seem that this method of setting the environment variable doesn't work since running the command `env` returns the following:

```
SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/su
LOGNAME=root
MAIL=/var/mail/root
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/usr/local/sge/bin/fbsd-amd64
SUDO_GID=1001
PWD=/usr/home/ec2-user
TERM=xterm
HOME=/root
USER=root
SHELL=/bin/sh
SUDO_USER=ec2-user
SUDO_UID=1001
USERNAME=root
```

I do however notice that the `PATH` variable which I have also configured via root's `~/.profile` to include the Open Grid Scheduler binaries would seem to have been successfully set.

I have also found that performing the same configuration in non-root accounts on the same machine succeeds in setting the environmental variable. In addition, exporting the value in the global `/etc/profile` seems to produce the same behaviour.

I am therefore wondering if perhaps there is a better way of setting this variable for the root account under the Bourne shell?

I understand that it would probably be easier to use tcsh as root's default shell, as this is typically how FreeBSD is configured. However I have thus far had to compile Open Grid Scheduler without support for tcsh due to issues with `utmp.h` no longer being available in FreeBSD.

Comment: I think you first need to declare it and then you export it

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you have SUDO environment variables, so I assume you are running this by using sudo. To test, I set my root user's shell to /bin/sh and added

> SGE_ROOT="/usr/local/sge"
>
> export SGE_ROOT

to my /root/.profile

And I don't see the environment variable if I simply run "sudo sh", but I do have it if I run "sudo -i" or "sudo su -" so it seems like the issue has more to do with the way sudo is used than the shell.